# Kernel module driver programming (motivation)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, osdev

Are there whatsoever some kinds of directives linux kernel developers go for, especially when writing drivers? - How drivers in the linux kernel are maintained. How can I (as a normal distro User) say if a driver works performant and is not just functioning.

Comment: look into the linux-kernel tag info wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux-kernel/info

Comment: You might enjoy the Eudyptula Challenge: http://eudyptula-challenge.org/ .

Comment: Thanks! i will give it a try - see how it goes.